# Get debug output from Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

From [Python PIL incorrectly decoding TIFF colors (using incorrect colorspace)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12900656/1709587), I infer that it used to be possible to get PIL to dump a bunch of useful debugging output by setting `PIL.Image.DEBUG = True`. However, this attribute no longer exists; per https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1191 it looks like it was replaced by usage of the built-in logging module a few years ago.

However, if I do

```
import logging
logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('Test')  # Trigger installation of default StreamHandler
from PIL import Image
Image.open('my_picture.tif').show()
```

then I get no logging output besides my 'Test' message.

What do I need to do to see debug logging from Pillow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the TIFF output that you're interested in -

```
from PIL import Image, TiffImagePlugin
TiffImagePlugin.DEBUG = True
Image.open('my_picture.tif')
```

Comment: Huh. This works for me (with Pillow 5.2.0), but it definitely ain't using the standard logging system as https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1191 implies. I dunno what's changed in Pillow's internals since then. But regardless, this is useful!